# GEnerate and send images with text value as pdf using mailgun and mern

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, mailgun

Hi I have an mern app where user inserts data into a frontend, they also select images
I want the data that they pass into the fields to be applied into a pdf template along with the selected images and sent a mail adress using mail gun

Frontend code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import { Container, Row, Col, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import FrontPlaceholderImage from '../../assets/Front.png';
import DotPlaceholderImage from '../../assets/Dot.png';
import BranchSelect from '../modules/BobilPage/BranchSelect'; // Import the BranchSelect component
import FormField from '../modules/BobilPage/FormField'; // Import the FormField component
import bobilSchema from '../modules/BobilPage/BobilSchema'; // Import your validation schema
import CustomFileUploadField from '../modules/BobilPage/CustomFileUploadField';
import CustomTextAreaField from '../modules/CustomTextAreaField';
import FormData from 'form-data'; // Add this import

function Bobil() {
  const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState({
    frontImage: null,
    dotnrImage: null,
  });
  const FrontPlaceholder = FrontPlaceholderImage;
  const DotPlaceholder = DotPlaceholderImage;

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      selectedBranch: '',
      regnummer: '',
      route: '',
      model: '',
      merke: '',
      arsmodel: '',
      elOppvarmet: '',
      gummlistEllerLimt: '',
      sensor: '',
      kamera: '',
      hoydeTopp: '',
      breddeBunn: '',
      message: '',
    },
    validationSchema: bobilSchema, // Use your validation schema

onSubmit: async (values) => {
  try {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('formData', JSON.stringify({ ...values, selectedImages }));

    const response = await fetch('/api/submit-form', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      // Handle success (e.g., show a success message)
      alert('Form submitted successfully');
    } else {
      // Handle server error
      alert('Form submission failed');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle network or other errors
    console.error(error);
    alert('An error occurred while submitting the form');
  }
},
});

const handleFrontImageChange = (event) => {
  const selectedImage = event.currentTarget.files[0];
  formik.setFieldValue('frontImage', selectedImage);
  setSelectedImages({ ...selectedImages, frontImage: URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage) });
};

const handleDotImageChange = (event) => {
  const selectedImage = event.currentTarget.files[0];
  formik.setFieldValue('dotnrImage', selectedImage);
  setSelectedImages({ ...selectedImages, dotnrImage: URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage) });
};
// Log the selectedImages object to the console
console.log('Selected Images:', selectedImages);

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <h1 className="text-center mt-4 mb-5">Bobil Skjema</h1>
        <Form noValidate onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
        <Row>
  {/* Select Branch */}
  <Col className="text-center" xs={12} lg={12}>
    <BranchSelect
      name="selectedBranch" 
      id="selectedBranch" 
      value={formik.values.selectedBranch} // Pass the correct value prop
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      error={formik.touched.selectedBranch && formik.errors.selectedBranch}
    />
  </Col>
</Row>


          {/* Bil Informasjon */}
          <Row>
            <h2 className="text-center mt-4 mb-5">Bil Informasjon</h2>
            <Col lg={6}>
            <FormField
  label="Regnummer"
  name="regnummer"
  type="text"
  id="form-regnummer" 
  value={formik.values.regnummer}
  onChange={formik.handleChange}
  onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
  error={formik.touched.regnummer && formik.errors.regnummer}
  isValid={formik.touched.regnummer && !formik.errors.regnummer} // Pass isValid based on whether the field is valid
/>

            </Col>
            <Col lg={6}>
            <FormField
  label="Velg Rute"
  name="route"
  type="select"
  id="form-route" 
  value={formik.values.route}
  onChange={formik.handleChange}
  onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
  error={formik.touched.route && formik.errors.route}
  isValid={formik.touched.route && !formik.errors.route} // Pass isValid based on whether the field is valid
>
  <option value="">Velg en rute</option>
  <option value="front">Front</option>
  <option value="side">Side</option>
  <option value="bak">Bak</option>
</FormField>

            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row className='mt-5'>
  <Col lg={6}>
    <FormField
      label="Model"
      name="model"
      type="text"
      id="form-model" 
      value={formik.values.model}
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      error={formik.touched.model && formik.errors.model}
      isValid={formik.touched.model && !formik.errors.model} 
    />
  </Col>
  <Col lg={6}>
    <FormField
      label="Velg Merke"
      name="merke"
      type="select"
      id="form-merke" 
      value={formik.values.merke}
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      error={formik.touched.merke && formik.errors.merke}
      isValid={formik.touched.merke && !formik.errors.merke} 
    >
      <option value="">Velg et merke</option>
      <option value="hymer">Hymer</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    </FormField>
  </Col>
</Row>

<Row className='mt-5'>
  <Col lg={6}>
    <FormField
      label="Årsmodel"
      name="arsmodel"
      type="number"
      id="form-arsmodel" 
      placeholder="2023"
      value={formik.values.arsmodel}
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      error={formik.touched.arsmodel && formik.errors.arsmodel}
      isValid={formik.touched.arsmodel && !formik.errors.arsmodel} 
    />
  </Col>
</Row>

<Row className='mt-5'>
    <hr></hr>
<h2 className="text-center mt-4 mb-5">Bil Detaljer</h2>
  <Col lg={6}>
    <FormField
      label="El-Oppvarmet"
      name="elOppvarmet"
      type="select"
      id="form-elOppvarmet" 
      value={formik.values.elOppvarmet}
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      error={formik.touched.elOppvarmet && formik.errors.elOppvarmet}
      isValid={formik.touched.elOppvarmet && !formik.errors.elOppvarmet} 
    >
      <option value="">Velg et valg</option>
      <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
      <option value="Nei">Nei</option>
    </FormField>
  </Col>
  <Col lg={6}>
    <FormField
      label="Gummlist eller Limt"
      name="gummlistEllerLimt"
      type="select"
      id="form-gummlistEllerLimt" 
      value={formik.values.gummlistEllerLimt}
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      error={formik.touched.gummlistEllerLimt && formik.errors.gummlistEllerLimt}
      isValid={formik.touched.gummlistEllerLimt && !formik.errors.gummlistEllerLimt} 
    >
      <option value="">Velg et valg</option>
      <option value="Gummilist">Gummilist</option>
      <option value="Limt">Limt</option>
    </FormField>
  </Col>
</Row>

<Row className='mt-5'>
  <Col lg={6}>
    <FormField
      label="Sensor"
      name="sensor"
      type="select"
      id="form-sensor" 
      value={formik.values.sensor}
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      error={formik.touched.sensor && formik.errors.sensor}
      isValid={formik.touched.sensor && !formik.errors.sensor} 
    >
      <option value="">Velg et valg</option>
      <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
      <option value="Nei">Nei</option>
    </FormField>
  </Col>
  <Col lg={6}>
    <FormField
      label="Kamera"
      name="kamera"
      type="select"
      id="form-kamera" 
      value={formik.values.kamera}
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      error={formik.touched.kamera && formik.errors.kamera}
      isValid={formik.touched.kamera && !formik.errors.kamera} 
    >
      <option value="">Velg et valg</option>
      <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
      <option value="Nei">Nei</option>
    </FormField>
  </Col>
</Row>


<Row className='mt-5'>
  <Col lg={6}>
    <FormField
      label="Høyde topp midt på ruten"
      name="hoydeTopp"
      type="number"
      id="form-hoydeTopp" 
      value={formik.values.hoydeTopp}
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      error={formik.touched.hoydeTopp && formik.errors.hoydeTopp}
      isValid={formik.touched.hoydeTopp && !formik.errors.hoydeTopp} 
    />
  </Col>
  <Col lg={6}>
    <FormField
      label="Bredde bunn"
      name="breddeBunn"
      type="number"
      id="form-breddeBunn" 
      value={formik.values.breddeBunn}
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      error={formik.touched.breddeBunn && formik.errors.breddeBunn}
      isValid={formik.touched.breddeBunn && !formik.errors.breddeBunn} 
    />
  </Col>
</Row>

<Row className='mt-5'>
    <hr></hr>
<h2 className="text-center mt-4 mb-5">Bilder</h2>
  <Col className='text-center' xs={6} lg={6}>
    <CustomFileUploadField
      label="Bilde Av Front"
      name="frontImage"
      id="frontImage" 
      value={formik.values.frontImage}
      onChange={handleFrontImageChange}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      error={formik.touched.frontImage && !formik.values.frontImage}
      selectedImage={selectedImages.frontImage}
      placeholderImage={FrontPlaceholder}
    />
  </Col>
  <Col className='text-center' xs={6} lg={6}>
  <CustomFileUploadField
      label="Bilde Av DotNr"
      name="dotnrImage"
      id="dotnrImage" 
      value={formik.values.dotnrImage}
      onChange={handleDotImageChange}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      error={formik.touched.dotnrImage && !formik.values.dotnrImage}
      selectedImage={selectedImages.dotnrImage}
      placeholderImage={DotPlaceholder}
    />
  </Col>
</Row>


<Row className="mt-4">
    <hr></hr>
<p>Behøver du å legge til en ekstra beskjed til lageret?</p>
  <Col lg={12}>
    <CustomTextAreaField
      label=""
      name="message"
      id="form-message" 
      value={formik.values.message}
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
    />
  </Col>
</Row>

<Row className="text-center mt-4 mb-5">
        <Col lg={12}>
          <Button
            size="lg"
            variant="primary"
            style={{ width: '60%' }}
            type="submit"
            disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
          >
            Send Inn
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Bobil;
```

BackendLogic

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const Mailgun = require('mailgun-js');
const generatePdf = require('./generatePdfs'); // Import the generatePdf function
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');

const storage = multer.memoryStorage(); // Store files in memory
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/submit-form', upload.array('file'), async function (req, res) {
  try {
    // Extract form data from the request body
    const formData = JSON.parse(req.body.formData);

    // Generate the PDF using the form data
    const pdfBytes = await generatePdf(formData);

    // Initialize the Mailgun API client
    const mailgun = new Mailgun({
      apiKey: 'palceholder', // Your Mailgun API key
      domain: 'splaceholder', 
    });
  

    // Create the mail data object
    const mailData = {
      from: 'noreply@buddy.com', // Sender's email address
      to: 'test@test.com', // Recipient's email address
      subject: 'Bobil',
      attachment: [
        {
          data: pdfBytes,
          filename: 'form.pdf',
          contentType: 'application/pdf',
        },
      ],
    };

    // Send the email
    mailgun.messages().send(mailData, (error, body) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
      } else {
        console.log(body);
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Form submitted successfully' });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

generator

```
const { PDFDocument, rgb } = require('pdf-lib');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const createPdfWithImages = async (formData, frontImage, dotnrImage) => {
  // Create a new PDF document
  const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.create();
  const page = pdfDoc.addPage([600, 400]);
  const { width, height } = page.getSize();

  // Add content to the page
  page.drawText(`Form Data: ${JSON.stringify(formData, null, 2)}`, {
    x: 50,
    y: height - 50,
    size: 12,
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0),
  });

  // Add frontImage and dotnrImage to the PDF (assuming they are file paths)
  if (frontImage) {
    const frontImageBytes = await fs.readFile(frontImage);
    const frontImageXObject = await pdfDoc.embedPng(frontImageBytes);
    page.drawImage(frontImageXObject, { x: 50, y: height - 150, width: 100, height: 100 });
  }

  if (dotnrImage) {
    const dotnrImageBytes = await fs.readFile(dotnrImage);
    const dotnrImageXObject = await pdfDoc.embedPng(dotnrImageBytes);
    page.drawImage(dotnrImageXObject, { x: 200, y: height - 150, width: 100, height: 100 });
  }

  // Serialize the PDF to bytes
  const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();

  // Save the PDF to a file (optional)
  await fs.writeFile('output.pdf', pdfBytes);

  return pdfBytes;
};

module.exports = createPdfWithImages;
```

Want the data inserted from frontend to be generated into a pdf and sendt as attachment to mail using mailgun